# twilio - Enqueued call - How to Dequeue?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm currently working on a Twilio queuing system but I'm stuck on how to dequeue the call and connect to an agent.

I have all the calls stacking up in the queue and my understanding was that we need to call Dequeue and below was the sample response available in twilio site.

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Queue>foo</Queue>
    </Dial>
<Response>
```

But, this can be sent as a response to twilio when someone calls twilio.

So, Should an agent call a twilio number? If so, Do we need to maintain an internal number for this case, apart from the support number that we have for incoming calls?

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baskar, hello. Megan from Twilio here.

There are two main ways that you may choose to handle this scenario if you have not already come up with a solution.

First, is how you currently seem to be pursuing it using [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) and [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue) in which the implementation will follow this flow. And you can [see the tutorial for this call queue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/callqueue) with examples in PHP and Python.

[image]

In this example, you need to maintain a number for customers to call and a number for agents. [This is an older example](https://github.com/RobSpectre/Twilio-Queue-Example), but it might help conceptually.

Second, is with TaskRouter [as discussed in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575064/twilio-connecting-an-enqueued-call-to-an-agent/33577896#33577896).

I hope this proves to be helpful.